# Parsing HTML page in web crawler

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, html-parsing, urllib2

I am trying to build a web crawler that crawls all the links on the page and adds them to a file.

My Python code contains a method that does the following:-

1. Opens a given web page(urllib2 module is used)
2. Checks if the HTTP header **Content-Type** contains **text/html**
3. Converts the raw HTML response into readable code and stores it into **html_string** variable.
4. It then creates an instance of the **Link_Finder** class which takes attributes base url(Spider_url) and page url(page_url). Link_Finder is defined in another module link_finder.py.
5. **html_string** is then fed to the class using  feed function.

Link_Finder class is explained in details below.

```
def gather_links(page_url):     #page_url is relative url
        html_string=''
        try :
            req=urllib2.urlopen(page_url)
            head=urllib2.Request(page_url)
            if 'text/html' in head.get_header('Content-Type'):              
                html_bytes=req.read()
                html_string=html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
            finder=LinkFinder(Spider.base_url,page_url)
            finder.feed(html_string)            
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception " + str(e)
            return set()
        return finder.page_links()
```

The link_finder.py module uses standard Python **HTMLParser** and **urlparse** modules. Class Link_Finder inherits from **HTMLParser** and overrides the handle_starttag function to get all the **a** tags with href attribute and add the url's to a set(self.queue)

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser 
import urlparse     
class LinkFinder(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self,base_url,page_url):       #page_url is relative url 
        super(LinkFinder,self).__init__()      
        self.base_url=base_url
        self.page_url=page_url
        self.links=set()
    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):    #Override default handler methods
        if tag==a:
            for(key,value) in attrs:
                if key=='href':
                    url=urlparse.urljoin(self.base_url,value) #Get exact url
                    self.links.add(url)
    def error(self,message):
        pass
    def page_links(self):     #return set of links
        return self.links
```

I am getting an exception

> argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

I think the problem in the way i used urllib2 Request to check the header content. 
I am a bit new to this so some explanation would be good

Comment: Complete error output might have been much better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have used BeautifulSoup instead of HTMLParser like so -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageContent)
links = soup.find_all('a')
```